# run external .exe via c++

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess

what i tried to do: do start an external .exe file (which is compiled from fortran) on windows via another c++ program

I have tried many different versions, like:

```
system("C:/IPSE_temp/CEA_schwing.exe");
```

compiling was ok, but when i executed the file he missed some libraries such as RUND32.dll...

Then i tried to use this kind of code (CreateProcess) in different variations

```
std::string rt = "C:/IPSE_temp/CEA_schwing.exe";

STARTUPINFO info = { sizeof(info) };
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;

if (CreateProcess(NULL, (LPWSTR) rt.c_str(), NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo);)
    {
    WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
    }
```

cause i wanna know too, when the program is finished (program should wait until external .exe has finished it's work). Compiling was ok, but he never runs the .exe

I hope that i skipped nothing in de description, an i'm looking forward to your help. Thanks in advance

And yes, i'm new into programming in c++ ;)

best regards

---

hanks to Barmak Shemirani, the program is now running.

unfortunately there is an additional error:

my CEA_schwing.exe is reading a file "SINGLE_TP.inp" from the same directory. this is working fine wenn i run die exe through the windows explorer.

But by running the .exe through my c++ program, he isn't able to find the file anymore. Does anybody know why he doesn't get the file anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rt.c_str()` should be the first parameter in `CreateProcess()`.

Moreover, you are mixing ANSI and Unicode. You are clearly compiling for Unicode, where `CreateProcess()` maps to `CreateProcessW()`.  `std::string` contains `char` data, so `c_str()` returns a `const char *` pointer, but `CreateProcessW()` is expecting a `wchar_t*` pointer instead.  Casting with `(LPWSTR)rt.c_str()` will simply hide the compiler error, but it doesn't fix the actual problem of you passing ANSI data where Unicode data is expected.

Use a wide string instead when declaring Unicode strings (Note the `L` prefix):

```
std::wstring rt = L"C:/IPSE_temp/CEA_schwing.exe";
if (CreateProcess(rt.c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo))
...
```

That works because `rt.c_str()` is now compatible with the first parameter of `CreateProcess()`, which is an `LPCWSTR` and will accept a `const wchar_t *` pointer from `c_str()` (the second parameter does not accept a `const` pointer).

Alternatively, you can declare `wchar_t buf[MAX_PATH]` and use it as the second parameter in `CreateProcess()`, which is of type `LPWSTR` (non-const):

```
wchar_t buf[MAX_PATH];
wcscpy_s(buf, L"C:/IPSE_temp/CEA_schwing.exe");
CreateProcess(0, buf, ...);
```

---

You can also set the working directory in the 8th parameter:

```
wchar_t buf[MAX_PATH];
wcscpy_s(buf, L"C:\\IPSE_temp\\CEA_schwing.exe");

std::wstring dir = L"C:\\IPSE_temp";
CreateProcess(0, buf, NULL, NULL, TRUE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, dir.c_str(), &si, &pi);
```

Comment: You are welcome. See edit for setting the working directory.

Comment: _Alternatively, you can declare wchar_t buf[MAX_PATH] and use it as the second parameter_ - Not required. Just do `CreateProcess(NULL, &rt[0], ...`. It should also be pointed out that foreslashes are not recommended to use as path separators. The valid path separator for Windows is the backslash, if the foreslash works you are just lucky that the particular API you are using happens to support them.

Comment: thanks guys! 
for my problem i am now using the solution from barmak Shemirani!

Comment: @zett42: just note that the internal contents of `std::(w)string` are not guaranteed to be null-terminated until C++11, so `&rt[0]` **may or may not** work correctly, depending on your STL's implementation.  In practice, it is usually safe for most implementations, as they tend to be null-terminated internally so `c_str()` can just return the internal data pointer as-is. But this is also not guaranteed until C++11.  So, just be careful when using `&rt[0]`